# ButtonDownFcn of a tool on Matlab GUIDE toolbar is not working

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have written a GUI program in Matlab using Matlab GUIDE.
Created a tool on the toolbar and wrote a right click call back function as shown below, but when I do a right click on that tool on the GUI, there is no response.

```
function MyTool_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
waitfor(msgbox('Hello button down function','Hello button down'));
disp('Hello disp');
```

From property inspector, value of ButtonDownFcn is:

```
@(hObject,eventdata)main('MyTool_ButtonDownFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

I tried to debug using another button with Callback function to execute 'keyboard'.

```
function bugfindbutton_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
keyboard
```

This confirmed the existance of function `MyTool_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)` associated with `ButtonDownFcn` of the tool and is not deleted by any other functions. But a right click on the tool gives neither msgbox nor command window output.

I want right click of mouse on 'MyTool' toggle button (a custom tool on the toolbar) to execute `MyTool_ButtonDownFcn` function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ButtonDownFcn` is ignored for `uitoggletool` and `uipushtool` objects. You should instead use the `ClickedCallback` property to set a callback. That callback, however, will only execute on a left mouse click and will not be triggered on a right mouse click.

If you really need to bind a callback to a right mouse click, you can use the [`findjobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) utility from the file exchange to access the underlying Java object and assign a custom callback

```
h = uitoggletool( ...
    'CData',        rand(16, 16, 3), ...
    'OnCallback',   @(s,e)disp('on'), ...
    'OffCallback',  @(s,e)disp('off'));

% Get the underlying java object using findobj
jtoggle = findjobj(h);

% Specify a callback to be triggered on any mouse release event
set(jtoggle, 'MouseReleasedCallback', @(s,e)callback(h,e))

function callback(src, evnt)
    if evnt.getButton() == 3
        disp('Right Click!')
    end

    % Get the handles struct
    handles = guidata(src);

    % Modify the handles
    handles.value = 2;

    % Save the handles
    guidata(src, handles);
end
```

Comment: The Toggle Tool button `MyTool` has valid `OnCallback` and `OffCallback` functions. Hence cannot use `ClickedCallback` for one more task. With `MouseReleasedCallback`, the function executes for both, Left click release and Right click release. So cannot use this callback as it interferes with Left click for `OnCallback` and `OffCallback`. Thanks for info on `findjobj` though it did not solve the problem. I wanted to add one more function to `MyTool` toggle button. I thought right click is the only way. Have any more idea to do that?

Comment: @Govinda I've updated the example to be a little more thorough. You can definitely use `OnCallback` and `OffCallback` in conjunction with with the `MouseReleasedCallback` you just have to make the callback check that it was the right button that was clicked. See my update.

Comment: This worked until I realized that `handles` need to be updated inside the callback function. Callback functions have `callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)` syntax, so I did not specifically ask. But I need `handles` too to be updated inside the callback. Could you please help me to do that too?

Comment: @Govinda Updated to include an example of that